# Setting GUI Visible Environment Variables with OS Catalina

Tags: catalina, xcode, environment-variables

I need to set a number of Environment variables that can be seen by GUI apps (i.e. Xcode). When running from a terminal this is trivial and is simply a case of adding a. number of `export` commands to my `.bash_profile` e.g.

```
export BOOST_INCLUDE=~/boost/boost-XXXX/boost
```

Unfortunately GUI apps do not see values set in `.bash_profile`. I am using Catalina and it appears that Apple modifies the mechanism every time MacOs is updated. Many online guides are out of date....

This article: http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-mac-os-x-launchd-plist/ suggests that `launchctl` should do what I need but even the following simple example does not work:

In a terminal:

```
/bin/launchctl setenv FOO BAR
```

Then close the terminal and open a new one

Check the value:

```
echo $FOO
```

The output should be

```
BAR
```

But it is unset. Note it is also unset in the original terminal so I am not convinced that the command `/bin/launchctl setenv FOO BAR` is doing anything.

Note: This is about setting the environment variable for GUI apps NOT just for the terminal.

Comment: Do you need to set these variables particularly in Xcode? Because there's more specific way to set env vars in Xcode

Comment: I am looking for a way to set the variables such that I do not need to manually set them on a per project basis. My current work around is to use some symbolic links  point to the latest version of the 3rd part library I am using (e.g. boost or range-v3). That way in the Xcode projects I can use the links and adjust them when I upgrade the library,

Comment: Have you tried starting Xcode from Terminal like this: `open /Applications/Xcode.app`? Xcode should inherit variables set in that shell.

Comment: @jaume are you sure that works. Open will launch from desktop

Comment: @mmmmmm The folder from where you run `open` in Terminal  is not relevant as long as the environment variables are set. The OP should confirm whether it works for him.

Comment: Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385934/877069

Answer (score 4):

Run `launchctl setenv FOO BAR` in Terminal.app, then *quit* (<kbd>Cmd-Q</kbd>) and restart Terminal.

Comment: That is exactly what the OP says he has done and that it does not work

Comment: OP says `a terminal`, I say `Terminal.app`.

Comment: Ah you need to emphasise the difference

Comment: Given your question https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/394979/237 will this work for xcode as the op asks?

Comment: No idea, this is why I formulated my answer as `Try [...]` but it was then reformulated to @nohillside. What I am sure is that setting global variables has never worked for me in `iTerm` but it has worked using `Terminal.app`. I hope `Xcode` is just like other GUI apps.

Comment: If you set the variable in Terminal it's available in a newly started iTerm afterwards, so I would assume it works for Xcode as well. About iTerm changes not working I have no clue :-)

Comment: Wow, so how to make it automatically, do not want to manually set in Terminal.app everytime.

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but I have no idea what the difference is between "a terminal" and "Terminal.app". Googling is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know “environment variables” set via launchctl are not visible in the shell and vice versa. Therefore I set some variables with launchctl *and* as shell variables (in my shell init file), if I need them in both, e.g. JAVA_HOME