# Launchctl setenv in Terminal.app vs iTerm

Tags: terminal, iterm, environment-variables

If I use

```
launchctl setenv FOO BAR
```

in Terminal.app, after closing and reopening the app, the variable `FOO` is correctly set.

If I do the same thing in iTerm, nothing happens.

Why?

Comment: Hi Damien, welcome to Ask Different. How do you test that `FOO` is correctly set?

Comment: Via `echo $FOO`

Comment: When I run `launchctl setenv FOO BAR` and then, in the same Terminal window, I run `echo $FOO`, I get an empty line, that is, the variable has not been set. I've tested it with `zsh` and `bash`. Could you check if `FOO` is set before running `launchctl`?

Comment: Yes works 100%. Please `quit Terminal.app` and start it again before doing `echo $FOO`.